# Rails 6 - params not passing to insert into db

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been going in circles with this one.
The params are not passed into the database.

=> Rails 6.0.3 application

**My model and schema:**

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
end
```

```
create_table "roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "role_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
end
```

**Controller**

```
def create
    @role = Role.new(params[:role_params])
    @role.save
    redirect_to @role
end
```

with the private method:

```
private
    def role_params
        params.require(:role).permit(:role_name)
    end
```

The object gets created, but the 'role_name' column is null.
Log:

```
Started POST "/roles" for ::1 at 2020-05-18 18:31:16 +0200
Processing by RolesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"TZR2usGh+M66S1Nky8fhR7esIoAlYfSUImPY58Yck+7OYmHlYa2Px7eXCByg0rA8NJoV++mS8OxTCc+GfWFO0Q==", "role"=>{"role_name"=>"ragarg"}, "commit"=>"Save Role"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:17:in `create'
  Role Create (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "roles" ("created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?)  [["created_at", "2020-05-18 16:31:16.064816"], ["updated_at", "2020-05-18 16:31:16.064816"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:17:in `create'
   (12.6ms)  commit transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/roles_controller.rb:17:in `create'
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/roles/14
Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 14.1ms | Allocations: 7243)
```

Comment: `@role = Role.new(params[:role_params])` should be  `@role = Role.new(role_params)` in order to use the strong params

Comment: @dbugger Thank you for your help, that was it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `create` method is just a little off

```
def create
  @role = Role.new(role_params)
  @role.save
  redirect_to @role
end
```

Should work

Answer (score 1):

Change

`@role = Role.new(params[:role_params])`

To

`@role = Role.new(role_params)`

And if want to access the params in controller you can use
`params[:role][:role_name]`